# Displaying Parent and Child Categories separately

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I would like to display my posts in a grid with the Parent Category displayed separately to the sub category, like so:

```
PARENT CATEGORY
Post Title
SUB/CHILD CATEGORY
```

At the moment I am using this code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="col col-sm-6 col-md-4 clearfix single-resource mix all <?php $category = get_the_category(); $secondCategory = $category[1]->cat_name; echo str_replace(' ', '', $secondCategory); ?> " data-ref="mixitup-target">
                                    <article class="resource-container">
                                        <div class="image"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );  ?></div>
                                        <div class="details">
                                            <span class="cat">
                                            <?php $category = get_the_category();
                    $firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name; echo $firstCategory;?>  </span>
                                            <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
                                            <span class="cat-sub"><?php $category = get_the_category(); $secondCategory = $category[1]->cat_name; echo $secondCategory;?></span>

                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                </a>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But this seems inconsistent as sometimes the Parent Appears where the child should and vice versa.

How can I order the posts to display in the correct place or hopefully just call the parent and sub categories separately? The child category also needs to be added as a class to the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `wp_get_object_terms` set all this at the start of the loop and then use the variables don't call the function everytime..

Also think on cases where there is more than 1 parent category.

```
$parent_categories = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'category', array('parent'=>0));
// can be more than 1 parent... so you maybe want to loop.
$parent_category = $parent_categories[0]; // get first parent category
// array of child categories for the parent category for this post.
$child_categories = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'category', array('parent'=>$parent_category->term_id));
$first_child_category = $child_categories[0]; // get first parent category
```

This is how you should use it. you can improve it by adding a loops for the categories to check if there is more than 1 parent or more than 1 child...

Also you can do the conditions in the html before the container for the cat or child cat in order to remove the container if the cats doesn't exists.

For the classes better use the category slug.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    $parent_categories = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'category', array('parent'=>0));
    $cat_classes = array();
    // can be more than 1 parent... so you maybe want to loop.
    if($parent_categories) {
        $parent_category = $parent_categories[0]; // get first parent category
        $cat_classes[] = $parent_category->slug;
        // array of child categories for the parent category for this post.
        $child_categories = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'category', array('parent'=>$parent_category->term_id));
        if($child_categories) {
            $first_child_category = $child_categories[0]; // get first parent category
            $cat_classes[] = $first_child_category->slug;
        }
    }

    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="col col-sm-6 col-md-4 clearfix single-resource mix all <?php echo implode(' ', $cat_classes); ?>" data-ref="mixitup-target">
        <article class="resource-container">
            <div class="image"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );  ?></div>
            <div class="details">
                <span class="cat">
                    <?php echo ($parent_category) ? $parent_category->name : ''; ?>
                </span>
                <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
                <span class="cat-sub">
                    <?php echo ($first_child_category) ? $first_child_category->name : ''; ?>
                </span>

            </div>
        </article>
    </a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: @creativepearson I added a code to the answer to show you how to use it.